# Lambdas with captured variables

Tags: variables, c#-3.0, subsonic, lambda

Consider the following line of code:

```
private void DoThis() {
    int i = 5;
    var repo = new ReportsRepository<RptCriteriaHint>();

    // This does NOT work
    var query1 = repo.Find(x => x.CriteriaTypeID == i).ToList<RptCriteriaHint>();      

    // This DOES work
    var query1 = repo.Find(x => x.CriteriaTypeID == 5).ToList<RptCriteriaHint>();    
}
```

So when I hardwire an actual number into the lambda function, it works fine.  When I use a captured variable into the expression it comes back with the following error:

> No mapping exists from object type
>   ReportBuilder.Reporter+<>c__DisplayClass0
>   to a known managed provider native
>   type.

Why?  How can I fix it?

Comment: I guess not. I'll keep that in mind for the future...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, the correct way to fix this is for the framework that is accepting the expression tree from your lambda to evaluate the `i` reference; in other words, it's a LINQ framework limitation for some specific framework. What it is currently trying to do is interpret the `i` as a member access on some type known to it (the provider) from the database. Because of the way lambda variable capture works, the `i` local variable is actually a field on a hidden class, the one with the funny name, that the provider doesn't recognize.

So, it's a framework problem.

If you really must get by, you could construct the expression manually, like this:

```
ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(RptCriteriaHint), "x");
var query = repo.Find(
    Expression.Lambda<Func<RptCriteriaHint,bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                x,
                typeof(RptCriteriaHint).GetProperty("CriteriaTypeID")),
            Expression.Constant(i)),
        x)).ToList();
```

... but that's just masochism.

Your comment on this entry prompts me to explain further.

Lambdas are convertible into one of two types: a delegate with the correct signature, or an `Expression<TDelegate>` of the correct signature. LINQ to external databases (as opposed to any kind of in-memory query) works using the second kind of conversion.

The compiler converts lambda expressions into expression trees, roughly speaking, by:

1. The syntax tree is parsed by the compiler - this happens for all code.
2. The syntax tree is rewritten after taking into account variable capture. Capturing variables is just like in a normal delegate or lambda - so display classes get created, and captured locals get moved into them (this is the same behaviour as variable capture in C# 2.0 anonymous delegates).
3. The new syntax tree is converted into a series of calls to the `Expression` class so that, at runtime, an object tree is created that faithfully represents the parsed text.

LINQ to external data sources is supposed to take this expression tree and interpret it for its semantic content, and interpret symbolic expressions inside the tree as either referring to things specific to its context (e.g. columns in the DB), or immediate values to convert. Usually, System.Reflection is used to look for framework-specific attributes to guide this conversion.

However, it looks like SubSonic is not properly treating symbolic references that it cannot find domain-specific correspondences for; rather than evaluating the symbolic references, it's just punting. Thus, it's a SubSonic problem.

Comment: The framework is SubSonic 3.0.  But shouldn't the comparison expression be evaluated before being passed into the .Find method?  Seeing, how the comparison expression is a regular c# code?

Comment: No, the comparison expression is *not* evaluated before being passed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll hit up the SubSonic author and see why it does not process captured variables.

Comment: I've updated my post. Actually, the expression tree I'm manually creating above is an approximation of what is occurring for your working case, except rather than Expression.Constant(i), the compiler would generate Expression.Constant(5).

Comment: Confirmed. It's a known issue in SubSonic 3 and will be worked on next week.

Comment: Update.  SubSonic 3 Alpha now supports captured variables.